# Using Profile properties in ASP pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, profile, imageurl

I want to have part of the URL address (a directory name) of my images in the `aspx` file in a profile Property. In this case the Property is called `ThemeDir`, something like this:

```
  <asp:Image ID="MyImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="/UserResources/" 
+ Profile.ThemeDir + "/Save.png" />
```

maybe using Eval or `<# ?`

I don't want to do it in the server side for some specific reasons, 
it has to be in the same aspx file.